# Multiple order bys in cosmos

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on a sorting system that has 5 fields that can be sorted by in any arbitrary order and direction.

Cosmos does not support order by on multiple fields without a composite index.

My solution is to create a composite index programatically as order by queries are made by the user - is this a scalable or 'correct' solution?

Otherwise how would I make cosmos work properly in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing what you suggest is not scalable as it takes time to build the index. If you want queries to work when called you will need to create the index ahead of time.

Comment: Unfortunately the combination of sortable permutations is too big to pre-calculate (could end up in the thousands!) - does cosmos simply not support the sort of ordering I'm trying to do?

Comment: It does but your performance will only be good with composite indexes. The only thing I could suggest is to not apply a sort order in the query and do the sort in memory, client side.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I suspect the equivalent would be to copy the entire data off the database and then do a sort which might be a slow/expensive operation but will see what I can do.

I might instead clone the cosmos data into elasticsearch for the purposes of sorting and querying quickly..

Comment: For full text search Cosmos has a connector for Azure Search and easy setup in Azure portal you can try as well.